# MVVM: Communicate child Fragment to parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a parent Fragment that has ViewPager which holds another Fragments(child). Some child Fragment can have list. If the user press a back button the list will scroll up if can scroll vertically, another press on back button will move the ViewPager to first item (Fragment).

While I can create an approach like this on child Fragment.

```
if (adapter.currentList.isNotEmpty() && recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1))
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0)
        else {
            try {
                val parentFragment: HomeFragment = parentFragment as HomeFragment
                parentFragment.onBackPressed()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e)
            }
        }
```

And a public method on parent Fragment like this

```
fun onBackPressed() {
        if (viewPager.currentItem != 0)
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0, true)
        else
            requireActivity().onBackPressed()
    }
```

I am not sure if this is the best thing to do since I read that Fragments should better not communicate directly with each other, instead communication should be handle by the host Activity or shared ViewModel. But doing so seems an overkill and I do not feel the use of LiveData just for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the `SharedViewModel` approach, its kinda built for this. Your child `Fragments` are effecting the `ViewPager` that belongs to the `ParentFragment`. They are effectively part of the same `View` but the child `Fragments` don't have access to the `View` that contains them. So using a `SharedViewModel` can bridge the gap.

What I would do is make a well defined interface that manipulates the `ViewPager` and its `Adapter` as you see fit for your application. That interface should then be accessible through the `SharedViewModel`.

In the interface you could have a function called `navigateToFragment(Class fragmentClass);` In this function you would then need to find a fragment via its class inside the `Adapter`, and then use the `ViewPager` to go to it. Ie `navigateToFragment(HomeFragment.class);`